# iframe in FireFox sometimes pops up a "Save As..." dialog rather than loading the frame

Tags: firefox, iframe, savefiledialog

I integrate phpBB on my site using iframe. It mostly works seamlessly and all looks great.

Sometimes, for reasons I haven't figured out, the following page will not try to load the iframe in FireFox (will work on IE/Chrome) but instead open the "Save As..." (or open/save) dialog indicating the .php file has been served as text rather than as real php. Now I would gladly blame the server but this doesn't happen on some of my FireFox browsers and doesn't happen on other browsers. The link:

http://colnect.com/en/forum/index%21

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show some of the code you used?

Comment: The link I've written has the entire HTML that loads the iframe. Here's the iframe tag of it: <iframe id="ext" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 9000px;" src="/forums/index.php?"></iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your server doesn't know how to parse PHP files, so it's thinking it's a file to download.

Do you have PHP installed on the server?

Update:

Seems you do. But try this:

Rather than:

http://colnect.com/en/forum/index%21

Do

http://colnect.com/en/forum/index.php

Comment: Thanks Ryan, there is PHP installed and working well. The page on http://colnect.com/en/forum/index%21 returns an HTML source with the iframe inside it. There's no problem getting the HTML but sometimes the internal frame isn't loading. Mostly it does.

Comment: This problems doesn't happen anymore and perhaps it was due to server rules choosing not to parse the request as PHP. It's now working well for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This happens beacuse your url ends with %21 which is encoded as "!" and so the file is not recognized or not readable by the browser.

Thus it offers to download the "!" extension file...

Comment: Thanks Trufa. If this was the case it would never work. You can see that it mostly does. And %21 is a valid part of a URL AFAIK.

Comment: Yes but safari seams to parse: <iframe id="ext" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 9000px;" src="/forums/index.php?"></iframe>